# How can I efficiently cut out part of a video?

Tags: python, video, moviepy

I want to remove the first few seconds from a video that's about 25 minutes long. I found the `moviepy` package, and tried writing this code:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
clip = VideoFileClip("video1.mp4").cutout(0, 7)
clip.write_videofile("test.mp4")
```

However, it's very slow even for a single video. Is there a faster way to do this in Python?

Comment: Writing the video probably means that the library has to re-encode it, resulting in a loss of quality and poor performance. It *is* possible to cut away from a MP4 video stream without re-encoding, but it's not as simple as you seem to think it is, and you can't cut at arbitrary points (only right before keyframes). I also don't know if moviepy can do this.

Comment: I agree with @cemper93. MoviePy always decode your frames (to Numpy arrays) and reencode them at write time, which takes time. The simplest way to cut without reencoding is to use FFMPEG to extract the right segment from the mp4. You can do it directly at the command line, or from Python, using the subprocess library to call ffmpeg.

Comment: @Zulko: Can you write that as an answer and add a bit more explanation? I have no idea about FFMPEG and the subprocess library you are talking about. :/

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Try this and tell us if it is faster (if it can, it will extract the video directly using ffmpeg, without decoding and reencoding):

```
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip
ffmpeg_extract_subclip("video1.mp4", start_time, end_time, targetname="test.mp4")
```

If that doesn't help, have a look at the [code](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/master/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_tools.py#L27)

Comment: How is the smallest unit of time that t1,t2 can be ?

Comment: What happens if I dont wanna cut on non key frames? Can I cut anywhere with this code?

Comment: would this work with other video formats like mkv? or would there be adverse effects? I did it on an mkv and it works but when the file launches in vlc it glitches for half a second

Comment: is there a way to run with re encode flag? I think the glitch might be due to where the video has inserted key frames?

Comment: from moviepy.editor import *  //  
video = VideoFileClip("myHolidays.mp4").subclip(50,60)  //  this line is from their page https://pypi.org/project/moviepy/ and is up to date.

Comment: units of start_time and end_time are in millisecond.

Comment: is there a moviepy function i can use where i can add timestamps instead of seconds?

Comment: small note - in the version you get with pip, the keywords are "t1" and "t2" instead of "start_time" and "end_time"

Answer (score 19):

If you are new to **moviepy** you should follow these steps.

### Installation :

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org moviepy
pip install imageio-ffmpeg
```

### Installation (in your virtualenv) version for old systems :

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org moviepy
python
import imageio
imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
```

After these commands, you have the minimal software requirements.

### Usage

```
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip
# ffmpeg_extract_subclip("full.mp4", start_seconds, end_seconds, targetname="cut.mp4")
ffmpeg_extract_subclip("full.mp4", 60, 300, targetname="cut.mp4")
```

Comment: Btw, if you are looking to disable the output of `ffmpeg_extract_subclip` that not possible with the current version. You should install moviepy from the [git](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy) repo because they actually recently added that option.

Answer (score 6):

```
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip
ffmpeg_extract_subclip("video1.mp4", t1, t2, targetname="test.mp4")
```

t1 and t2 in this code represent the start time and end time for trimming.  Video before t1 and after t2 will be omitted.

Answer (score 6):

The `ffmpeg_extract_subclip` did not produce correct results for me for some videos. The following code from this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/moviepy-getting-cut-out-of-video-file-clip/) worked though.

```
# Import everything needed to edit video clips
from moviepy.editor import *

# loading video gfg
clip = VideoFileClip("geeks.mp4")
# getting only first 5 seconds
clip = clip.subclip(0, 5)
# showing clip
clip.ipython_display(width = 360)
```

Then you can save the clip as follows:

```
clip.write_videofile("clip.mp4")
```

Comment: It worked almost fine. Somehow the sound wasn't exported. Any idea?