# How to split a video in parts using Python?

Tags: python, video, compression, txt

I need to split a video file of any size into various parts of maximum size of up to 75 MB. I found this code, but it doesn't work:

```
import cv

capture = cv.CaptureFromFile(filename)
while Condition1:
    # Need a frame to get the output video dimensions
    frame = cv.RetrieveFrame(capture) # Will return None if there are no frames
    # New video file
    video_out = cv.CreateVideoWriter(output_filenameX, CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), capture.fps, frame.size(), 1)
    # Write the frames
    cv.WriteFrame(video_out, frame)
    while Condition2:
        frame = cv.RetrieveFrame(capture) # Will return None if there are no frames
        cv.WriteFrame(video_out, frame)
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317140/cutting-out-a-portion-of-video-python) is a good start

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script I just created using MoviePy. But instead of dividing by byte-size it divides by video length. So if you set `divide_into_count` to 5 and you have a video of length 22 minutes, then you get videos of length 5, 5, 5, 5, 2 minutes.

```py
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
from time import sleep

full_video = "full.mp4"
current_duration = VideoFileClip(full_video).duration
divide_into_count = 5
single_duration = current_duration/divide_into_count
current_video = f"{current_duration}.mp4"

while current_duration > single_duration:
    clip = VideoFileClip(full_video).subclip(current_duration-single_duration, current_duration)
    current_duration -= single_duration
    current_video = f"{current_duration}.mp4"
    clip.to_videofile(current_video, codec="libx264", temp_audiofile='temp-audio.m4a', remove_temp=True, audio_codec='aac')

    print("-----------------###-----------------")
```

Comment: a user has suggested to use `>=` instead of `>` in the while statement

Answer (score 0):

Avne Desta's solution ( which is great and helped me really ),
with some slight changes
I consider this a bit more readable code in my humble opinion ( really no offense ! ) since it goes not reverse and some minor naming things.
It uses a bit more convenient file names (also imho), part_1 part_2 etc.
It splits into chunks of fixed time.

All credits shall go the original creator, not me !

```
full_video = r"20secs.mp4"
partDura = 8 # duration of a part in seconds

from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
from time import sleep

fullDura = VideoFileClip(full_video).duration
startPos = 0

i = 1 
while True:
    endPos = startPos + partDura

    if endPos > fullDura:
        endPos = fullDura

    clip = VideoFileClip(full_video).subclip(startPos, endPos)

    part_name = "part_"+str(i)+".mp4"
    clip.to_videofile(part_name, codec="libx264", temp_audiofile='temp-audio.m4a', remove_temp=True, audio_codec='aac')
    print("part ",i,"done")
    i += 1
    
    startPos = endPos # jump to next clip
    
    if startPos >= fullDura:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use this working example to get two halves of your video, you
> can adjust the code accordingly with the 'divide_into_count = 2'
> statement for more video parts than 2, note that the last statement of
> the function erases the original input video file

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
import os

def split_videos(unsplit_videos_directory):
    files = [file_name for file_name in os.listdir(unsplit_videos_directory) if file_name.endswith(".mp4")]

    for file_name in files:
        input_video_path = os.path.join(unsplit_videos_directory, file_name)

        clip = VideoFileClip(input_video_path)
        current_duration = clip.duration
        divide_into_count = 2  # You can adjust this value as needed
        single_duration = current_duration / divide_into_count

        while current_duration > single_duration:
            # Split the video into two equal halves
            subclip = clip.subclip(current_duration - single_duration, current_duration)

            # Save each subclip with the original filename and appropriate suffix
            file_base_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_name)
            first_half_filename = os.path.join(unsplit_videos_directory, f"{file_base_name}_part2{file_extension}")
            second_half_filename = os.path.join(unsplit_videos_directory, f"{file_base_name}_part1{file_extension}")

            subclip.to_videofile(first_half_filename, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac")
            subclip.close()  # Close the subclip before creating the second one

            # Create the second subclip
            subclip = clip.subclip(current_duration - 2 * single_duration, current_duration - single_duration)
            subclip.to_videofile(second_half_filename, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac")

            # Close the second subclip
        subclip.close()

            # Update current_duration for the next iteration
            current_duration -= single_duration

            print(f"Video split and saved: {first_half_filename} and {second_half_filename}")

        # Remove the original video
        os.remove(input_video_path)

# Example usage
unsplit_videos_directory = "/path/to/unsplit_videos"
split_videos(unsplit_videos_directory)
```