# How to read a specific frame to a specific frame from video using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, video, frame

I want to read from  a specific frame to a specific frame in a video. For example , my video consists of 150 frames, but I want to read the video from frame 5th to frame 134th in that video. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to read your video and store it into a multi-dimensional numpy array. Afterwards you can slice the numpy array according to your requirements

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42166299/4141279 on how to read a video into a numpy array.

Slicing is then done by:

```
buf[4:134] # assuming buf is your numpy array from the previous step
```

You could also drop all the unnecessary frames during initial creation of the numpy array if you have memory limitations.

```
idx = 0
while (fc < frameCount  and ret):
    ret, tmp = cap.read()
    if fc in range(4, 135):
        buf[idx] = tmp
        idx += 1
    fc += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this :

This probably uses less opencv than you want, but I personally believe that ffmpeg is more adapted to this kind of operation

```py
import cv2
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip

def get_framerate(video)->float:
    """ this function was made to extract the framerate from a video"""
    # Find OpenCV version
    (major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver) = (cv2.__version__).split('.')
    if int(major_ver)  < 3 :
        return video.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
    else :
        return = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # get start frame
    videoName = input("Path of the video file ?")
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(videoName);
    fps = get_framerate(video)
    frame_start = int(input("Starting frame ?\n"))
    ts_start = frame_start / fps
    frame_end = int(input("Ending frame ?\n"))
    ts_end = frame_end / fps
    ffmpeg_extract_subclip(frameName, ts_start, ts_end, targetname="output.mp4")
```

source 1 : [an openCV guide](https://learnopencv.com/how-to-find-frame-rate-or-frames-per-second-fps-in-opencv-python-cpp/)

source 2 : [another question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317140/cutting-out-a-portion-of-video-python)